# Aurelia Validation - one of two fields must be mandatory

Tags: aurelia

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">SKU</label>
            <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="production.Sku1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">SKU</label>
            <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="production.Sku2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the textboxes above, either sku1 must be mandatory or sku2. I know how to do this in what seems like everything but Aurelia.

I was hoping it would be something simple like

```
this.validator = this.validation.on(this)
    .ensure('production.StockStatusId').isGreaterThan(0).withMessage('is required')
    .ensure('production.Sku1').isNotEmpty().Or.ensure('production.Sku2').isNotEmpty();
```

I have touched on if statements but unsure what the computedFrom would be

UPDATE

I was hoping this would work, however it isn't. Anyone know why?

```
.ensure('production.Sku1', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['HasProvidedEitherSku'])})
.passes(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku }).withMessage("(Need to provide a SKU)")

get HasProvidedEitherSku(){
    if ((this.production.Sku1 === undefined || this.production.Sku1 === null) && (this.production.Sku2 === undefined || this.production.Sku2 === null)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

UPDATE

This does work, in a way. However both show the error straight away however the error is only cleared on the one that has become valid. I understand why as the error message is attached to each one sep, however I dont know how to stop this

```
                .ensure('production.Sku1', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['HasProvidedEitherSku'])})
                .if(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku })
                    .isNotEmpty().withMessage('a SKU is required')
                .endIf()
                .ensure('production.Sku2', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['HasProvidedEitherSku'])})
                .if(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku })
                    .isNotEmpty().withMessage(‘a SKU is required')
                .endIf();
```

Comment: Try .when like this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137697/aurelia-validation-applying-some-rule-on-change-and-some-on-blur-on-same-proper?rq=1  Make one required .when the other is empty.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have used:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">SKU</label>
            <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="Sku1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label"> SKU</label>
            <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="Sku2">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Validation**

```
                    .ensure('Sku1', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['Sku1, Sku2'])})
                    .if(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku1OrSku2 === false })
                        .isNotEmpty().withMessage(‘at least one sku is required')
                        .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
                    .endIf()                    
                    .ensure('Sku2', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['Sku1, Sku2'])})
                    .if(() => { return this.HasProvidedEitherSku1OrSku2 === false })
                        .isNotEmpty().withMessage(‘at least one sku is required’)
                        .hasLengthBetween(0, 50)
                    .endIf();
```

**Validation Method**

```
get HasProvidedEitherSku1OrSku2 (){
    if ((this.Sku1 === undefined || this.Sku1 === null || this.Sku1 === '') && (this.Sku2=== undefined || this.Sku2=== null || this.Sku2=== '')){
        return false;
    } else {   
        return true;
    }
}
```